# Why python progress bar starts after completing the download

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, progress-bar

I put a progress bar to my python program ,
But it start after the download is completed.

I downloaded a big file and it started after a lot of time.
When progress bar started from 0% the file was already downloaded.

What can I do for it ?
I need it to be displayed at the start of the download .

Full code : https://github.com/GH0STH4CKER/Youtube_to_mp3/blob/main/Youtube_to_mp3.py

Progressbar code :

```
def download(url, fname):
    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    total = float(content_length)
    with open(fname, 'wb') as file, tqdm(
            desc=fname,
            total=total,
            unit='iB',
            unit_scale=True,
            unit_divisor=1024,
    ) as bar:
        for data in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            size = file.write(data)
            bar.update(size)

download(d_link,songname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to run it in a different Thread because I think it gets executed afterwards

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: Maybe this could help:https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-run-multiple-functions-at-the-same-time-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
    def progres_(self, streams, chunk, bytes_remaining):
        percentage = (float(abs(bytes_remaining - self.size_inBytes) / self.size_inBytes)) * float(100)
        self.progres_bar["value"] = percentage
        self.progres_bar.update()
        self.lbl_percentage.config(text=f" Downloading: {str(round(percentage, 2))}%")
        if round(percentage, 2) == 100:
            self.lbl_message.config(text="Download Completed", fg="green")
            self.btn_download.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
```